# Under Windows 7 is it possible to connect via Remote Desktop and have the remote host display remain active

Tags: windows-7, remote-desktop

Using Remote Desktop (not Remote Assistance) is there some way for the host display to be active during the remote session.

I want to connect to the Win7 box controlling our media center, but leave the monitor active to display the content.

In other words, use another computer as if it were a remote control

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can, but by using a different mode called Remote Control.

First of all you need to [use this patch to allow concurrent RDP sessions on Windows 7](http://deepxw.blogspot.com/2009/04/universal-termsrvdll-patch.html)  (this is not needed for Windows Server operating systems).

Then, in the remote session, go to Task Manager > Users tab, right click on the session you want to control (the console session), and choose Remote Control.

Comment: Just a note that this is a technical violation of your license agreement for Windows, but it's not something Microsoft is likely to come after you for.

Answer (score 1):

No, not using RDP. But if you install [VNC](http://www.tightvnc.com/), yes you can.